Wide Landscape Table to Fit Page Margins
I'm working on a document with a wide table in a landscape orientation using the pdflscape package. However, the table consistently exceeds the page margins, making it look cluttered and partially cut off when printed. Here is the simplified code for the table I am using:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{pdflscape} % Package for landscape pages

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
 \centering
 \caption{Summary of Variables Used in the Study}
 \label{tab:variables}
 \begin{tabular}{lll}
     \toprule
     \textbf{Variables} & \textbf{Definition \& Measurement} & \textbf{Source} \\
     \midrule
     EP\_1 & Energy poverty indicator: Proportion of the population with electricity access (\%) & WDI \\
     EP\_2 & Energy poverty indicator: Proportion of the population using clean cooking fuels and technologies (\%) & WDI \\
     EP\_3 & Energy poverty indicator: Proportion of the urban population with electricity access (\%) & WDI \\
     EP\_4 & Energy poverty indicator: Proportion of rural population with electricity access (\%) & WDI \\
     CEP & Composite energy poverty index & Author’s calculation \\
     Urbaz & Urbanization: Proportion of the population residing in urban areas (\%) & WDI \\
     GDP per capita & Gross domestic product: Log of Real GDP per capita & WDI \\
     Popul & Population growth rate & WDI \\
     Trans & Transport Composite Index: Pavement density (km/10,000 inhabitants); Road network density (km/km² of exploitable land) & AfDB \\
     Ele & Electricity Composite Index: Total national electricity supply (including imports) & AfDB \\
     ICT & ICT Composite Index: Mobile cellular penetration rate (per 100 inhabitants); Internet user penetration rate (per 100 inhabitants); Proportion of the population using the internet (\%) & AfDB \\
     WSS & WSS Composite Index: Safely managed water access rate (\%); Safely managed sanitation services coverage (\%) & AfDB \\
     AIDI & Africa Infrastructure Development Index: Composite Index using the sub-indexes of ICT subscriptions, Electricity, paved roads, and Sanitation and Water & AfDB \\
     lsanit & Sanitation: Log of proportion of the population using safely managed sanitation services & WDI \\
     linter & Telecommunication: Log of Internet security per million individuals and telephone malfunctions per 100 mainlines & WDI \\
     lelec\_power & Power: Log of percentage of electricity production lost in transmission and distribution & WDI \\
     ltransport & Transport: Log of Proportion of paved roads in the total road network & WDI \\
     lwater & Water: Log of Proportion of the population with access to safely managed water & WDI \\
     RE\_1 & Renewable electricity output: Share of renewable energy in electricity generation (\%) & WDI \\
     RE\_2 & Electricity generation from renewable energy sources, excluding hydroelectric power (kWh) & WDI \\
     Ineq & Income inequality index: Income inequality reflects the extent of disparity in the distribution of income within a population, measured by the share of income held by the richest 10\% of the population. & WIID \\
     LEG & Legatum Prosperity Index: A comprehensive index assessing holistic well-being, considering factors like economic performance, social equity, environmental sustainability, and governance. & Legatum Institute \\
     SC & Social capital: Benefits derived from social connections, including networks of relationships and shared values that facilitate cooperation among people, groups, and organizations. & Legatum Institute \\
     NE & Natural environment: Represents the world's stock of natural assets, including geological resources, soil, air, water, and living organisms. These assets provide ecosystem services that benefit humanity. & Legatum Institute \\
     SP & Social Progress Index: A composite indicator designed to evaluate the social well-being and progress of societies across various domains, incorporating dimensions such as basic human needs, well-being, opportunities, and social inclusion. & Social Progress Imperative \\
     PS & Political stability: Assesses perceptions of the likelihood of political instability or politically motivated violence, including terrorism. & WGI \\
     Rents & Natural resources: Total natural resources rents (\% of GDP) & WDI \\
     ODA & Official development assistance: Net ODA received (\% of GNI) & WDI \\
     \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}

output:


You could improve the table by using a fixed width second column, but even then the whole content won't fit on a single page.

why do you make life for your reader difficult by putting that (unordered) in a landscape table?  Make a normal, alphabetically sorted glossary with a description list.

I suggest you employ the xltabular package, which combines the capabilities of the longtable (ability to span more than one page) and tabularx (ability to set a target width -- here: \linewidth) packages. Be sure to allow automatic line breaking in columns 2 and 3.
In addition, I'd enable hanging indentation in columns 2 and 3. I'd also lose the bold-facing of the header rows.



\documentclass{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} 

\usepackage{xltabular} % combine strengths of 'longtable' and 'tabularx'
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \RaggedRight macro
\usepackage{calc}     % for \widthof macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em}p{\widthof{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} l L P{Imperative\quad} @{}}

   %% headers and footers

   \caption{Summary of variables used in the study}
   \label{tab:variables} \\
   \toprule
   Variables & Definition \& Measurement & Source \\
   \midrule
   \endfirsthead

   \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\tablename~\thetable, cont'd} \\[1ex]
   \toprule
   Variables & Definition \& Measurement & Source \\
   \midrule
   \endhead

   \midrule
   \multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (cont'd on next page)}\\
   \endfoot
   
   \bottomrule
   \endlastfoot
   
   
   %% body of table

   EP\_1 & Energy poverty indicator 1: Proportion of the population with electricity access (\%) & WDI \\
   EP\_2 & Energy poverty indicator 2: Proportion of the population using clean cooking fuels and technologies (\%) & WDI \\
   EP\_3 & Energy poverty indicator 3: Proportion of the urban population with electricity access (\%) & WDI \\
   EP\_4 & Energy poverty indicator 4: Proportion of rural population with electricity access (\%) & WDI \\
   CEP & Composite energy poverty index & Author’s calculation \\
   Urbaz & Urbanization: Proportion of the population residing in urban areas (\%) & WDI \\
   GDP per cap. & Gross domestic product: Log of Real GDP per capita & WDI \\
   Popul & Population growth rate & WDI \\
   Trans & Transport Composite Index: Pavement density (km/10,000 inhabitants); Road network density (km/km\textsuperscript{2} of exploitable land) & AfDB \\
   Ele & Electricity Composite Index: Total national electricity supply (including imports) & AfDB \\
   ICT & ICT Composite Index: Mobile cellular penetration rate (per 100 inhabitants); Internet user penetration rate (per 100 inhabitants); Proportion of the population using the internet (\%) & AfDB \\
   WSS & WSS Composite Index: Safely managed water access rate (\%); Safely managed sanitation services coverage (\%) & AfDB \\
   AIDI & Africa Infrastructure Development Index: Composite Index using the sub-indexes of ICT subscriptions, Electricity, paved roads, and Sanitation and Water & AfDB \\
   lsanit & Sanitation: Log of proportion of the population using safely managed sanitation services & WDI \\
   linter & Telecommunication: Log of Internet security per million individuals and telephone malfunctions per 100 mainlines & WDI \\
   lelec\_power & Power: Log of percentage of electricity production lost in transmission and distribution & WDI \\
   ltransport & Transport: Log of Proportion of paved roads in the total road network & WDI \\
   lwater & Water: Log of Proportion of the population with access to safely managed water & WDI \\
   RE\_1 & Renewable electricity output: Share of renewable energy in electricity generation (\%) & WDI \\
   RE\_2 & Electricity generation from renewable energy sources, excluding hydroelectric power (kWh) & WDI \\
   Ineq & Income inequality index: Income inequality reflects the extent of disparity in the distribution of income within a population, measured by the share of income held by the richest 10\% of the population. & WIID \\
   LEG & Legatum Prosperity Index: A comprehensive index assessing holistic well-being, considering factors like economic performance, social equity, environmental sustainability, and governance. & Legatum Institute \\
   SC & Social capital: Benefits derived from social connections, including networks of relationships and shared values that facilitate cooperation among people, groups, and organizations. & Legatum Institute \\
   NE & Natural environment: Represents the world's stock of natural assets, including geological resources, soil, air, water, and living organisms. These assets provide ecosystem services that benefit humanity. & Legatum Institute \\
   SP & Social Progress Index: A composite indicator designed to evaluate the social well-being and progress of societies across various domains, incorporating dimensions such as basic human needs, well-being, opportunities, and social inclusion. & Social Progress Imperative \\
   PS & Political stability: Assesses perceptions of the likelihood of political instability or politically motivated violence, including terrorism. & WGI \\
   Rents & Natural resources: Total natural resources rents (\% of GDP) & WDI \\
   ODA & Official development assistance: Net ODA received (\% of GNI) & WDI \\

\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}


Thank you so much. You are always so helpful ! ;)

An alternative solution is employ tabularray package. IN the second column I'd use X[j] column type, which  enable break long text into more lines. Also I'd condense linespread for text in cells end reduce rowsep to 1.2 pt.
Edit:
Considered @Mico comment I change rows separation to 1.3 and change linespread from 8.4 to 0.92.
Using aforementioned make the table code clear and quite short:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Summary of variables used in the study},
  label = {tab:variables} 
                ]{colspec = {@{} l 
                                 X[j]
                                 Q[l, wd=6em]
                             @{}
                             },
                  cells   = {font=\linespread{0.92}\selectfont},
                  row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
                  rowsep  = 1.3pt
                 }
   \toprule
Variables & Definition \& Measurement & Source \\
   \midrule
EP\_1       
    & Energy poverty indicator 1: Proportion of the population with electricity access (\%) 
        & WDI \\
EP\_2    
    & Energy poverty indicator 2: Proportion of the population using clean cooking fuels and technologies (\%) 
        & WDI \\
EP\_3 
    & Energy poverty indicator 3: Proportion of the urban population with electricity access (\%) 
        & WDI \\
EP\_4 
    & Energy poverty indicator 4: Proportion of rural population with electricity access (\%) 
        & WDI \\
CEP & Composite energy poverty index 
        & Author’s calculation \\
Urbaz 
    & Urbanization: Proportion of the population residing in urban areas (\%) 
        & WDI \\
GDP per cap.    
    & Gross domestic product: Log of Real GDP per capita 
        & WDI \\
Popul
    & Population growth rate 
        & WDI \\
Trans 
    & Transport Composite Index: Pavement density (km/10,000 inhabitants); Road network density (km/km\textsuperscript{2} of exploitable land) 
        & AfDB \\
Ele & Electricity Composite Index: Total national electricity supply (including imports) 
        & AfDB \\
ICT & ICT Composite Index: Mobile cellular penetration rate (per 100 inhabitants); Internet user penetration rate (per 100 inhabitants); Proportion of the population using the internet (\%)
        & AfDB \\
WSS & WSS Composite Index: Safely managed water access rate (\%); Safely managed sanitation services coverage (\%) 
        & AfDB \\
AIDI    
    & Africa Infrastructure Development Index: Composite Index using the sub-indexes of ICT subscriptions, Electricity, paved roads, and Sanitation and Water 
        & AfDB \\
lsanit
    & Sanitation: Log of proportion of the population using safely managed sanitation services 
        & WDI \\
linter 
    & Telecommunication: Log of Internet security per million individuals and telephone malfunctions per 100 mainlines 
        & WDI \\
lelec\_power 
    & Power: Log of percentage of electricity production lost in transmission and distribution 
        & WDI \\
ltransport 
    & Transport: Log of Proportion of paved roads in the total road network 
        & WDI \\
lwater 
    & Water: Log of Proportion of the population with access to safely managed water 
        & WDI \\
RE\_1
    & Renewable electricity output: Share of renewable energy in electricity generation (\%) 
        & WDI \\
RE\_2 
    & Electricity generation from renewable energy sources, excluding hydroelectric power (kWh)
        & WDI \\
Ineq 
    & Income inequality index: Income inequality reflects the extent of disparity in the distribution of income within a population, measured by the share of income held by the richest 10\% of the population. 
        & WIID \\
LEG & Legatum Prosperity Index: A comprehensive index assessing holistic well-being, considering factors like economic performance, social equity, environmental sustainability, and governance. 
        & Legatum Institute \\
SC  & Social capital: Benefits derived from social connections, including networks of relationships and shared values that facilitate cooperation among people, groups, and organizations. 
        & Legatum Institute \\
NE  & Natural environment: Represents the world's stock of natural assets, including geological resources, soil, air, water, and living organisms. These assets provide ecosystem services that benefit humanity. 
        & Legatum Institute \\
SP  & Social Progress Index: A composite indicator designed to evaluate the social well-being and progress of societies across various domains, incorporating dimensions such as basic human needs, well-being, opportunities, and social inclusion. 
        & Social Progress Imperative \\
PS  & Political stability: Assesses perceptions of the likelihood of political instability or politically motivated violence, including terrorism.
        & WGI \\
Rents   
    & Natural resources: Total natural resources rents (\% of GDP) 
        & WDI \\
ODA & Official development assistance: Net ODA received (\% of GNI) 
        & WDI \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}



+1. I assume that the purpose of font=\linespread{0.84} is to produce some visual grouping. If that's the purpose, something like font=\linespread{0.95} will also get the job done, but without the (to me) extreme line compression.

@Mico, thank you very much. Yes, I use linespread for visual grouping content of rows. Now I increase it from 0.84 to `0.92˛ans also increase a wee bit  row separation.
